# Can't link static lib for android NDK, cygwin gcc

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, cygwin, linkage

I have PROJ4 library, succesfully compiled under cygwin and installed to /usr/local.

I'm trying to compile as:

`$ arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o conftest -mthumb   temp.c -lproj  -L/usr/local/lib -lproj -lz  -lm -ldl`

`C:/dev/Android/android-ndk-r7c/android-8-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lproj
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that android-gcc doesn't understand cygwin path, so we need to use windows path:

`$ arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o conftest -mthumb temp.c -lproj -Lc:/path/to/lib -lproj -lz -lm -ldl`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o conftest -mthumb temp.c /usr/local/lib/libproj.a -lz -lm -ldl
```